# Find the constant $a$ so that the max rate of change of $T$ at $P(1,1,1)$ equals 3x the rate at which $T$ is changing in the $y$ direction

Tags: calculus, word-problem

Suppose that the temperature $T$ in $R^3$ is given by $T(x,y,z)=x^2+y+az^3$. Find the constant $a$ so that the maximum rate of change of $T$ at $P(1,1,1)$ equals three times the rate at which $T$ is changing in the $y$ direction

Looking for some help with this exam review question.

Comment: Could you double check the problem?  It seems like it's missing information.

Comment: Just edited and forgot the say it was changing in the y direction

Comment: Could really use some help

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** The maximum rate of change is in the direction of $\nabla T$ and the rate 
of change is $|\nabla T$|.

**Hint 2:** The rate of change of temperature in the $y$ direction is given by the directional derivative $D_y T = \hat j \cdot \nabla T$.

Comment: What is j and how do I factor in the 3 times the rate at which T is changing in the y direction

Comment: It's standard notation that $\hat j$ is the unit vector in the $y$-direction, i.e. $\hat j = \langle 0, \, 1 , \, 0 \rangle$. I will let you think about the second part of your question ... think about what the question is saying and how the quantities are related.

Comment: Okay so I have calculated my lengths of gradient T to be sqrt(5)+3a

Comment: From the given information, $|\nabla T| = 3|D_y T|$.